# More formal way to say "on autopilot"

Tags: synonyms, formality

I'd like to say that some process will continue for a long time without the need for much external guidance. Colloquially, I would say something like

> The process is on autopilot.

Is there a non-verbose way to say this without resorting to slang?

Comment: Not needing any external control:  "The process is fully automated".

Answer (score 2):

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/autonomous

*autonomous*

"(of a vehicle) navigated and maneuvered by a computer, without a need for human control or intervention under normal road conditions:
autonomous vehicle."

> The process is *autonomous*.

Answer (score 0):

Self-regulating often works.  If you want to get more descriptive about processes refer to feedback loops (positive and negative which regulate), open and closed, and emergent structure and complexity.

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to it as an *automatic* process, *automated* process, or (possibly in some contexts) an *autonomic* process.

Answer (score 0):

On its own. Without any intervention. Automatically.